# How can I access mounted BaseSpace data from the Apache server on localhost? [I am using Xampp on Ubuntu]

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I have Ubuntu Xampp installed at '/opt/lampp/' with the document root set to '/opt/lampp/htdocs/'.

The mounted BaseSpace is also located in the document root, containing various files such as FASTQ, BAM, and VCF.

I aim to access the BaseSpace folder data from the Apache server, specifically to read the VCF file and display it in the web browser.

The BaseSpace folder's file system is 'fuse.basemount.' I have included the path to the mounted BaseSpace folder in the Apache configuration file.

```
Alias /basespace /opt/lampp/basespace/
    <Directory "/opt/lampp/basespace/">
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

After adding those lines, I restarted the Apache server. However, when I checked the BaseSpace folder from the web browser (Apache), I encountered an error.

```
Access forbidden!
You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403
localhost
Apache/2.4.56 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1t PHP/8.2.4 mod_perl/2.0.12 Perl/v5.34.1
```

If I check the error log, it is showing:

```
Permission denied: [client ::1:39888] AH00035: access to /basespace denied (filesystem path '/opt/lampp/basespace') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

So I want to print the header of vcf file which is present inside the "basespace/Project/ABC/ABC.vcf".